# Run a sub-routine within another sub-routine - Compile Error: Argument not optional

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub StoreQA(ShapeClicked As Shape)
MsgBox "yeee"
End Sub

Sub ThisIsToBeRun()
StoreQA
End Sub
```

I get Compile Error: Argument not optional.
I tried mentioning `StoreQA(ShapeClicked As Shape)` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Argument not optional

You are defining a parameter here, named `ShapeClicked`:

```
Sub StoreQA(ShapeClicked As Shape)
```

Because the parameter isn't `Optional`, an argument *must* be provided for this parameter by any code that means to  invoke this `StoreQA` procedure:

```
' gets the first Shape in Sheet1 (assumes it exists), then passes it to StoreQA:
StoreQA Sheet1.Shapes(1)
```

If the parameter isn't needed, remove it:

```
Sub StoreQA()
```

If it's needed in some places but not in others, consider making it `Optional`:

```
Sub StoreQA(Optional ByVal ShapeClicked As Shape)
```

Then you can invoke the procedure legally without supplying any parameters:

```
StoreQA '<~ compiles fine now
```

---

#### Optional Considerations

If the `StoreQA` procedure receives an `Optional` parameter, it needs to verify whether it received a valid object reference before using it - otherwise expect problems:

```
Sub StoreQA(Optional ByVal ShapeClicked As Shape)
    If ShapeClicked Is Nothing Then
        ' argument was not provided *or 'Nothing' was supplied*
        ''Debug.Print ShapeClicked.Name '<~ error 91
    Else
        ' ShapeClicked is holding a valid Shape object reference
        Debug.Print ShapeClicked.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

If `Optional` parameters are declared `As Variant` (explicitly or not), then you can use the `IsMissing` function to verify whether an optional parameter was supplied - useful when `Nothing` is also a valid, useful value to receive (for object references anyway - for plain value types it can remove the need to resort magic/hard-coded "invalid" values):

```
Sub StoreQA(Optional ByVal ShapeClicked As Variant)
    If IsMissing(ShapeClicked) Then '<~ only valid with an Optional+Variant parameter
        ' argument was not provided
        ''Debug.Print ShapeClicked.Name '<~ error 91
    ElseIf Not ShapedClicked Is Nothing Then
        ' ShapeClicked is holding a valid Shape object reference
        Debug.Print ShapeClicked.Name
    Else
        ' 'Nothing' was explicitly supplied
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```